# New York Vision Zero Data

Tags: data

I'm trying to open Vision Zero Data provided by NYC, but they've not provided any documentation or guidance.

Does anyone have any guidance? I'm ideally looking for such data in a CVS/excel type format, but am not sure whether this'll be available.

Files in the folder are .spx; .gdbtable and .gdbindexes

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/Vision-Zero-View-Data/y74e-vkxy

Comment: That's not a true "folder", but rather a [file geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n00000001000000). It's a proprietary format developed by Esri. ArcGIS, if you have access to it, is your best option for opening it, but I believe some of the open source GIS software packages have methods for reading (not writing) geodatabase data.